# Return to the beginning of a file after reading last line in python

Tags: python

I want to read a file line by line, but after reading the last line it should return to the beginning of the file.

Here is my code:

```
def readLabels(self, n):
    resline = np.empty([0,2])
    for i in range(0,n):
        line = (self.f2.readline()).split(',')
        line = [x for x in line if is_number(x)]
        line = [float(s) for s in line]
        line = np.asarray(line)
        resline = np.concatenate((resline, [line]),axis=0)
    return resline
```

This function returns n lines of the file as a batch. However, it should continuously return to the beginning of the file, so that I can read batches over and over again.
So how can I make readline return to the beginning?

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Apply a counter, and check if the lines in for loop is greater than counters result.If yes make your loop start again

Comment: Where is `f2` opened? Are there other methods that are reading, using `f2`?

Comment: alot of that can be shortened to `line = np.asarray([float(x) for x in self.f2.readline().split(',') if isnumber(x)])`

Comment: f2 was opened in the __init__ and is not used by any other method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should check what `readline()` returns. If it returns empty string, then you can go back to the beginning of the file.

```
def readLabels(self, n):
    resline = np.empty([0,2])
    for i in range(0,n):
        line = self.f2.readline()
        if not line:
            # back to top
            self.f2.seek(0)
            # read again
            line = self.f2.readline()
        line = line.split(',')
        line = [x for x in line if is_number(x)]
        line = [float(s) for s in line]
        line = np.asarray(line)
        resline = np.concatenate((resline, [line]),axis=0)
    return resline
```

Comment: `readline` will return `''` and not `None`. Your code is correct (I think) but your explanation is not.

Answer (score 2):

You can probably try `self.f2.seek(0)` after you read it the first time. This will set the offset position to 0.

Comment: But how do I know when I reached the last line to do seek (0)?

Comment: *But how do I know when I reached the last line to do seek (0)* When you try and read from the file and get nothing -- in Python, that is the end of the file.

Answer (score 1):

You have to seek the beginning of the file.

So in your case I think the file is `self.f2`, thus you have to use:

```
self.f2.seek(0)
```